# How to get the exacte value of an np.array?

Tags: python, precision, numpy-ndarray

I have just calculated a probability as an np.array:

```
Proba = [[7.4687206e-10]]
```

but when I compute the complement of this probability, I got:

```
Comp = 1- Proba = [[1.]]
```

The expected value is `Comp = [[0.99999999925]]`

Can any one please, clarify why np.arrays do not give the exact values, and what should i do to obtain the wanted value.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is correct. It's just the way it's printed. Try this

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=15)

Proba = np.array([[7.4687206e-10]])
output = 1 - Proba

print(output)
```

before your code

Comment: When I try your proposed code I get the exact value. But when I replace `Proba = np.array([[7.4687206e-10]])` by the output of my function, that is : `Proba = model.predict(img) = [[7.4687206e-10]]`; I get alwayes [[1.]].

Comment: @Nina: can't replicate that, since I have no way of knowing what the output of the function is

Comment: The output of my function is an np.array that is [[7.4687206e-10]]. Sorry, I am a little  bit new to python.

Comment: @Nina: but how do you *know* that's the real value, since it prints `1`??

Comment: I print the output of the function, it gives [[7.4687206e-10]]. And as we know `1 - 7.4687206e-10 = 0.99999999925`.

Comment: again, I can't reproduce that obviously, unless i have the code. Seems unlikely though

Comment: Thank you!!!. I cast the output of the function to float, then using your solution, I get the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `comp[0][0]` simply or 
if your np array is like this `[[2],[3],[5]...]` do this

```
comp = [i for j in comp for i in j]
```

Comment: My np.array is composed only of one cell that contains the probability. I have already tried this:    `Comp = np.array([0], dtype = float)`
                               `Comp[0] = 1 - Proba`  But I got the same result.

Comment: `In [5]: Comp = 1 - Proba[0][0]`

`In [6]: Comp`
`Out[6]: 0.999999999253128`